# Automatic 1 undelete vote for deleted answers?

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, undelete

The last couple of days, I've noticed that most deleted answers had a single undelete vote. To see if this was a coincidence or not, I deleted my last SO answer, hit refresh and saw that it too had a single undelete vote just seconds after deleting it. Why is this?

Comment: Interesting observation

Comment: Maybe the team figured that users object 99.9% of the time to having their questions or answers closed or deleted, so might as well just automate the process...

Comment: Just tried it on this question, there is an automatic undelete vote on my self-deleted answer.

Comment: After you delete your post and see the automatic undelete vote is cast, are you still able to cast an undelete vote of your own?

Comment: @Bill, I don't really _cast_ an undelete-vote on my own answer: I simply click "undelete" and the post is undeleted. Does that answer your question, or did I misunderstand?

Comment: @Bart: No, that answers it.  The same thing happens for me, I just wasn't sure if it was a moderator power or if that was for everyone.

Comment: @Bart I believe the only way you have to vote to undelete is if people other than you voted to delete.. so it's difficult to test this bug

Comment: Just undeleted @Fabian's answer and the [history](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/92215/revisions) shows that mine was the only undelete vote. I think this is just a bug.

Comment: @Earlz, you can test it yourself by deleting an answer of your own, and then hitting refresh: you'll see that it immediately has a single vote to undelete. You'll need to do this with a 10K+ account, otherwise you won't see deleted answers.

Comment: @Bart: You can always see your _own_ deleted answers - no 10K needed.

Comment: @Hendrik, ah, didn't know that. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There were 2 bugs in the count preloading compared to how it worked before, remedying one of those the other day exposed another.  Both are now fixed, this will work correctly after the next build.